# Get user count growth grouped by month in mysql

Tags: mysql, group

I need help writing a query to get the total number of records from a `users` table broken out by month. I want cumulative growth and not just the number of user records added within a given month. For example, i want something like this:

Scenario:

```
4 users were added in January
7 users were added in February
3 users were added in March
```

My query would return this:

```
Jan = 4 users
Feb = 11 users
March = 14 users
```

I will use the data to create a line graph showing the growth of the total user count over time.